# Using CGAL Libraries with Eclipse on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, cgal

I am trying to run some "[Hello world](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/tutorial_hello_world.html)" tests with CGAL libraries under Eclipse Oxygen, but I am failing with a dozen of undefined reference errors.

I followed the suggested [apt-driven installation method](https://www.cgal.org/download/linux.html) by running

```
sudo apt-get install libcgal-dev
sudo apt-get install libcgal-demo
```

But now I am completely lost on how to link the libraries and make Eclipse correctly include and use CGAL.

This is the program that I'm trying to build:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <sstream>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point_2;
int main()
{
  Point_2 p(0, 0.3), q, r(2, 0.9);
  {
    q  = Point_2(1, 0.6);
    std::cout << (CGAL::collinear(p,q,r) ? "collinear\n" : "not 
    collinear\n");
   }

   {
    std::istringstream input("0 0.3   1 0.6   2 0.9");
    input >> p >> q >> r;
    std::cout << (CGAL::collinear(p,q,r) ? "collinear\n" : "not 
    collinear\n");
    }

   {
    q = CGAL::midpoint(p,r);
    std::cout << (CGAL::collinear(p,q,r) ? "collinear\n" : "not 
    collinear\n");   
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

And this is an example of the errors that I'm receiving:

```
make all 
Building target: exact
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -o "exact"  ./exact.o   
./exact.o: In function `CGAL::Handle::Handle(CGAL::Handle const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/Handle.h:55: undefined reference to 
`CGAL::precondition_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
makefile:44: recipe for target 'exact' failed
```

I tried to include the directories where the GCAL libraries are located in Eclipse under the Cross G++ Linker and Cross GCC compiler, but to no avail.

Unfortunately I am a total beginner both in C++ programming and in Eclipse!

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: "-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib" are bad. What you want is "-lCGAL". I don't know eclipse so I can't tell you where you are supposed to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I have suffered through this multiple times. :D

Here are the lessons I have learned*:

1. Do not download cgal from the ubuntu repository - download from their website [and build from source](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html)
2. Make sure you have all the dependencies (boost, etc) installed
3. Right-click on your project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build ->Settings ->Tool Settings.

Under GCC C++ Linker:

add libraries CGAL,gmp,mpfr,boost_thread

set library search path: (your path)/CGAL-4.11.1/lib

Under GCC C++ Compiler: -> includes: add include path (yourpath)/CGAL-4.11.1/include/

Try now. If it still does not because you cannot dynamically link the right files, add "-rpath /home/merlin/UbuntuSoftware/CGAL-4.11.1/lib " under miscellaneous under the linker.

Hope that helps.

Merlin :)